# My index page is showing error when i declare while, endwhile

Tags: php

I create an index.php page with combine templete.html page for the main page for a system. When i run the index page it s

```html
<?php $tarikh_tempah=t arikh_seminggu(); ?>
<form action="tempah.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
  <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FF99CC">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
          <tr bgcolor="#FF99CC">
            <td colspan="2"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Masukkan Maklumat Tempahan</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#FF99CC">
            <td colspan="2"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;</font><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#FF99CC">
            <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Nama Penempah</font>
            </td>
            <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<input name="nama" type="text" id="nama">
</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#FF99CC">
            <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Jabatan</font>
            </td>
            <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
    <select name="jabatan" id="jabatan">
      <option>Bilik Matron 2</option>
      <option>Farmasi Wad</option>
      <option>Inspektor Kesihatan</option>
      <option>Kejuruteraan</option>
      <option>Keselematan</option>
      <option>Klinik Dada</option>
      <option>Klinik Metadon</option>
      <option>Neuro</option>
      <option>PA Pengarah</option>
      <option>Pengarah</option>
      <option>Penyelia Hospital</option>
      <option>Timb Pengarah</option>
    </select>
    </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#FF99CC">
            <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">No.Tel/Extension</font>
            </td>
            <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
    <input name="notel" type="text" id="notel" />
    </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Tarikh Tempahan</font>
          </td>
          <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
    <select name="hari" id="hari">
    <?php
     for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tarikh_tempah[0]);$i++) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$tarikh_tempah[0][$i];?>"><?=$tarikh_tempah[0][$i];?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </font>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FF99CC">
      <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Masa Tempahan</font>
      </td>
      <td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        <select name="waktu" id="waktu">
        <?php
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM 'waktu_tempah'";
        $qid = mysql_query($qry);
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qid)):
        ?>
         <option value="<?=$data['waktu'];?>"><?=$data['waktu'];?></option>
            <?php
            end while;
            ?>
            </select>
            </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FF99CC">
      <td colspan="2"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;</font><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FF99FF">
      <td colspan="2">
        <div align="center"> <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

how "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\book\templates\masuk_tempahan.html on line 135".

Comment: [`endwhile` keyword should contain no spaces.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: I'd also be mindfull of `<?=` short tags are not universally supported yet.  I think in 5.4 they are finally enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

The php 'while' statement ends with 'endwhile', not 'end while'. Remove the space and you should remove the error you're seeing. 
You have three php elements in a row in this code set:

```
    <?php
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM 'waktu_tempah'";
    $qid = mysql_query($qry);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qid)):
    ?>
        <option value="<?=$data['waktu'];?>"><?=$data['waktu'];?></option>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
```

The first one, containing the "while" statement ends immediately after you define the while condition. The second php statement is within the option html tag and the third simply holds the endwhile (which should be one word. I would recommend rewriting that sequence to the following:

```
    <?php
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM 'waktu_tempah'";
    $qid = mysql_query($qry);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qid)):
      { echo '<option value="'.$data['waktu'].'"><?='.$data['waktu'].'?></option>';}
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the while with {}

```
<?php
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qid))
{
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['waktu']; ?>"><?php echo $data['waktu']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```